# Fetch file's content from remote url into Smarty template

Tags: php, smarty

I got one script and the content of the Page is into home.tpl.

Now I want something like:

> Text Text Text "value of php file" Text Text Text...

My php file is:

```
<?php
    $btc4cents = file_get_contents("https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=USD&value=0.04");
?>
```

I have tryed so much already to add it.. with {php} tags, with creating some file with this code:

```
<?php
    function smarty_function_btc(array $params, Smarty_Template_Instance) {
        include 'btc.php';
    }
?>
```

and then make it like

> Text Text Text {btc} text text text...

But I'm only getting errors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fetch` Smarty function:

```
{* assign the fetched contents to a template variable *}
{fetch file='https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=USD&value=0.04' assign='btc'}
```

and then do:

```
Text Text Text {$btc} text text text...
```

Check the [documentation.](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.fetch.tpl)

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I must say, that I a absolutly smarty noob.. Where do I add: 

{* assign the fetched contents to a template variable *}
{fetch file='https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=USD&value=0.04' assign='btc'}

Comment: @Jerome well, since you use Smarty and you have `home.tpl` then you should display it there..

Comment: thanks! Works great! Could I ask you directly one other question please... I have some value inside of this: {$statistics.cashout} , how I can send this value to the link? Like {fetch file='https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=USD&value={$statistics.cashout}' assign='btc'} ... I try this already but only gives errors! Thanks again

Comment: try putting it like: `{fetch file='blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=USD&value=$statistics.cashout' assign='btc'}`

Comment: it dosent work... Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyException' with message '{fetch} cannot read resource 'blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=USD&value=$statistics.cashout''

Comment: Ok, this works fine, just tested it: `{{fetch file="https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=USD&value=\`$statistics.cashout\`" assign='btc'}}`